# Leaflet events to control other layers in a layer group

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

For a map that I am working on, I have several GeoJSON `FeatureCollection`s, one for each address in my data set. In each `FeatureCollection`, there is a `Point` marker for the address, as well as several `PolyLine`s representing routes to that address. I would like to do the following:

1) Initialize the map showing only the Address point markers.

2) On mouseover of the Address point marker, show ALL of the route polylines for that feature collection.

It seems fairly easy to attach an event to a given feature in a layer group (like trigger a popup or change marker color when the point is clicked). However, I can't find a way to trigger the *polylines* to show when the *point marker* is clicked. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the map with all the points and polylines, but hide the polylines setting opacity to 0 in the options.

There was a very similar question here: [Make Leafletmarkers searchable and blurr out the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050355/make-leafletmarkers-searchable-and-blurr-out-the-others/42052024#42052024)

You can use this example: https://yafred.github.io/leaflet-tests/20170205-newsrooms-and-articles/ but set opacity to 0